# Receiving BFSK with 9.6 khz deviation on TS-2000 / ICOM(IC-910H) in FM mode

Tags: kenwood, fm, icom

I have used Kenwood TS-2000 to receive BFSK signals with 3.3 khz deviation operating the TS-2000 in FM mode. Can we receive similar signals but whose BFSK deviation is 9.6 Khz using either the TS-2000 or the ICOM IC-910H transceiver? Do these transceivers support this large deviation? 
Also what are the software that can be used to decode the AF tones obtained from these transceivers?